# Powershell API access cookies credential

Tags: api, powershell, cookies, networkcredentials

I have a PowerShell script that I'm using to query an API. The script works and giving the the output I need. However, I have a concern with the cache credentials.
For some reason the script still runs even if I use incorrect login. I have a couple of access on the API. The case is that once an incorrect account is used, the script still works and it seems using the last account that works.

For example, I first use a correct account "Account1" and the script/access to API works.
When I try to use "Account2" and intentionally passing incorrect password, the script/access to the API still works. This is true even if I close and re-open another PowerShell Console. The only way clear the last account that works is by Clearing IE Cookies and Temp Internet files, so my guess is that the problem lies in there. If possible, I wouldn't want to clear ALL cookies or Temp files everytime the script runs. Is there a way to clear only cookies/temp files related to the script/api access? Or maybe put something on the script so not to created cookies/temp, but still allow API access to work?
Below are part of the script that I use.

```
$SecureUN = "Some Secure account"
$UNkey = "Some UNkey"
$UN = $SecureUN | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $UNkey
$UNBSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($UN)
$UnsecureUN = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($UNBSTR)
$SecurePW = "Some Secure password"
$PWkey = "Some PWKey"
$PW = $SecurePW | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $PWkey
$PWBSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($PW)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($('{0}:{1}' -f [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($UNBSTR), [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($PWBSTR))))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
$Query = "WebURL"
$Http_Request = New-Object -ComObject Msxml2.XMLHTTP
$Http_Request.open('GET', $QueryIncident, $false)
$Http_Request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", $basicAuthValue)
$Http_Request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.webssite.v1+xml")
$Http_Request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
$Http_Request.send()
$RequestStatus = $Http_Request.StatusText
Write-Host "Request Status: $RequestStatus"
```

The API output is a couple of pages and will only allow us max of 100 items per page so I have to repeat the query multiple times until all pages are completed.

```
X-Current-Page: 1
X-Per-Page: 100
X-Total-Count: 5783
X-Total-Pages: 58
```

Is this related to `RequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive")`? The script runs hourly everyday.

Comment: The caching might even happen at the server side which probably can't be controlled at all. Anyway, the thing what I would try here is to `send()` unique requests and add something like `+ "?Time=$((Get-Date).Ticks)"` to your query.